# RxJava Chaining Observables with flatmap / concatmap & observeOn threading

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

The code below....

- observes two integer streams from an Android ViewPager (pageSelected, scrollState).
- combines & filters the streams looking for a certain combination.
- if found, executes a network call.
- consumes the result of network call.

## Questions

**1. Is flatmap() / concatmap() the only way to chain Observables for the code below?** (To avoid nesting subscribe() call)

**2. Is the use of observeOn() to switch threads correct / intuitive in the flat code or is there a better way to do this?** (DataTools call is asynchronous)

I found applying the correct threading between Observable, Operator, and Subscriber confusing when using the nested code.

## Flat version

```
public void loadNextAtTest4(final int pagesRemaining) {
    ObservableCombineLatest.combineLatest(pageSelectObs, scrollStateObs, new BiFuncOnlyIdlePages()).filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(@NonNull Integer page) throws Exception {
            return page > -1 && pagesRemaining == page;
        }
    }).observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(new Function<Integer, Observable<List<PageDescriptor>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<PageDescriptor>> apply(@NonNull Integer integer) throws Exception {
            return DataTools.getNextPageBase(mRedClient, mFpxClient).toObservable();
        }
    }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<PageDescriptor>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull List<PageDescriptor> pageDescriptors) throws Exception {
            mCPAdapter.appendDataset(pageDescriptors);
        }
    });
}
```

## Nested version

```
public void loadNextAtTest2(final int pagesRemaining) {
    ObservableCombineLatest.combineLatest(pageSelectObs, scrollStateObs, new BiFuncOnlyIdlePages()).filter(new Predicate<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(@NonNull Integer page) throws Exception {
            return page > -1 && pagesRemaining == page;
        }
    }).observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Integer page) throws Exception {
            DataTools.getNextDataBase(mRedClient, mFpxClient)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<PageDescriptor>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(@NonNull List<PageDescriptor> pageDescriptors) throws Exception {
                            mCPAdapter.appendDataset(pageDescriptors);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Calling `subscribe` from within the `onNext` handler of another `subscribe` call is a bad practice. You loose composition of cancellation, error handling.

Comment: The Nested version was ugly v1.  Flat is v2, & what I'm using.  Questions are about whether there's a better way still.  ps. Do Kali?